Brown spots near the edge of Ginkgo biloba leaves
Brown spots have started to appear on my Ginkgo biloba leaves. The plant is only a few months old. What could be the issue? Initially, the spots were only present on one leaf, but now there is another leaf with brown spots. There are eight leaves on the plant. The plant is outdoors in a lowland tropical climate. It is in bright shade for most of the day, and gets 2 hours of direct sunlight right before sunset.



Are you watering or fertilizing?

I water almost daily. I occasionally fertilize (once a week maximum) using a dilute liquid fertilizer. Could the issue be caused by insufficient fertilization?
